# code only works in cmd and not in program

Tags: regex, perl, cmd

I have a series of one-liners in this program.  They will work individually in the cmd or if indiv. written out in the program, however, when they are all together I believe it is only the first one that works.  This is very troublesome considering I have a lot of data to work with and would much rather be able to execute this and others like it in a batch.  I am pretty new to perl and computer programming so I appologize for the beginner errors.  Any help will be great.

Thanks,
Josh

```
use strict;
use warnings;




LINE: while (<>) {
s/POSF /\n/gi;
s/,|\*|\\|\^|\"|=|\?|\$//gi;
s/^/\|/gi;
s/(\|)(number: .*?$|From \d+\/\d+\/\d+ to \d+\/\d+\/\d+|^Units|^Current Face|^Price|^FX|As of \d+\/\d+\/\d+)/$2/gi;
s/\| +|\|\t+/\|/gi;
s/\n/\t/gi;
s/\|/\n/gi;
s/^/\|/gi;
s/(\|)(.*?number: .*?$)/$2/gi;
s/\n//gi;
s/\|/\n/gi;

      print;
}
print "\n\ndone"
```

Comment: by the way...the actual words in this prog are not scalar variables..

Comment: [perldoc perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html).  Step through the loop, examining `$_` before and after the changes.  Also, please consider `tr/|/\n/`, `tr/\n//d`, etc., as well as changing the regex delimiter rather than backslashing (`\ `) your slashes (`/`).

Comment: As you are doing so much manipulation of newline characters in the file, you might have better luck reading the whole file in a single line. Put `$/=undef;` before your `while` loop. Also use the `/m` modifier on your 4th substitution (the one with `...^Units|^Current Price...`).

Comment: @joshE, Your claims are easily disproved by passing `POSF ***|number: 123`. The output is clearly affected by at least three of your substitutions. Could you please clarify what your problem actually is?

Answer (score 1):

Some of your one-liners (#1, #7 and #11) inserted lines. Some of your one-liners (#6 and #10) combined lines. This affects what subsequent one-liners treat as one line of input.

In your new program, this means that some substitutions see twice as much as their one-liner counterparts, or just a part.

You could solve this by readin the whole file at once by adding `local $/;`.

That said, I challenge your claim that your one-liners worked. For example, the 3rd pattern puts a `|` at the start of every line, so how can `^Units` ever match in the fourth pattern?

Comment: @ikegami...you are actually right about that one and the order..this is something I noticed later through furhter observation...always the little things, anyway, it still has some problems so if you have any solutions as to why else it might not work it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: As I previously requested, please specify what problem you are experiencing (by providing the input that produces the problem, along with the output you received and the output you expected).